# How to fix MapView zoom into location until a second time view appears

Tags: ios, zooming, mapkit

I have an app that loads a tabbarcontroller with 3 tabs.  One of them is a mapview.  It is set to zoom into the user's location by this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;

    //IF no city was selected, use userLocation as center
    if (!self.cityWasSelected) {
        zoomLocation.latitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        zoomLocation.longitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        CLLocationDistance visibleDistance = 5000; // 5 kilometers
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);


        [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    } else { //if a city was selected, use that city's value...this is actually the same right now, since self.userLocation is set appropriately elsewhere.
        //Set location from selection - forward geocode
        zoomLocation.latitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        zoomLocation.longitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        CLLocationDistance visibleDistance = 5000; // 5 kilometers
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);

        [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The initial tab is a tableviewcontroller for user preferences, the second tab is the mapview and the third is a tableview.  When I first tap on the mapview, the map shows the entire world :)  If i tap back to the initial tab or the list tab and then return to the mapview, the map is properly centered around my current location.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `showsUserLocation` on the map view will start searching for the user's location. This is an asynchronous operation and you cannot assume that `mapView.userLocation` will be valid immediately after settings `showsUserLocation` to YES.

The first time you view appears, you ask the map view to start location. `mapView.userLocation` probably returns nil. The second time around, the map view has probably finally gotten the user location and loads your map region successfully. This is sheer luck, and you should not rely that you will get location the second time (it may fail, take longer than usual).

When the map view has determined user location, it will call back on a delegate method ([MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)). You need to implement this delegate method like so:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    // We have location, do your logic of setting the map region here.
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.